# read value on xlsx file inside project folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an xlsx file stored on my project, I ma trying to access that file from a script to work with the data stored inside the xlsx file.

I have been playing around  for a while but I am not managing to access the data inside the file.
the idea is that from the command line I have to run a script that will get the data from the xlsx file and I would be able to generate a file and play with the data.

my project structure is

```
folder
   |-script.js
   |-file.xlsx
```

the way I am trying to import the data is

```
import * as xlsx from './file.xlsx'
console.log(xlsx)
```

I am running it from the console using npm run scriptname

the error I get is always the same

```
:1 - error TS1005: '{' expected.

2 import * as xlsx from './file.xlsx'

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1

 npm ERR! project@1.1.0 script: `npx ts-node --project ./scripts/imports/script.js`
```

I find this issue a bit overwhelming for me so every hint or advie will be much appreciated